# String comparations after post and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page where a textarea is filled with a value from database when the page loads. I want to see if the value was modified. 
I take the value from textarea using jquery:

```
fields.care_advice_message = $('#care_advice_message').val();
```

and send it through ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "page.php",
  data: fields
}).done(function(data){ ..}
```

On page.php, I compare the string received via ajax with the string from database and every time I receive that the strings are different.

```
if(trim($_POST['care_advice_message']) !== trim($organization_data['care_advice_message']))
{
    echo " different " . strlen($_POST['care_advice_message']) . " " .    strlen($organization_data['care_advice_message']);
}
else {
    echo " same ";
}
```

I used var_dump to see the strings on page.php

```
var_dump($_POST['care_advice_message']);
var_dump($organization_data['care_advice_message']);
```

and I receive this:

```
 <pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font    color='#cc0000'>'text line&#10;new text line&#10;another line'</font> <i>(length=36)</i>
  </pre><pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'text line&#13;&#10;new text line&#13;&#10;another line'</font> <i>(length=38)</i>
```

Why the string from ajax post has only the "& #10;" unicode but from database I have "& #13;" too?

If I submit the form, then the strings are the same.

Comment: This is not a definitive solution, so comment: try to wrap your response in JSON.

Comment: I'm sending my string message in a json, If this is what you mean. "fields" variable is a json

Comment: I was talking about the response (php) and besides that: fields is not json as far as I can see. call `.serializeObject()`

Comment: If you want to return it as a JSON, are you using proper headers for the response ?

Comment: I don't want to return it in a JSON, I just want to check if the text from textarea was modified. I used var_dump only to see how the strings are different.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends how your string is threaten before it is inserted in your DB.
As you may know, a new line in a string could be symbolized by "\r\n".

"& #10;" <=> \n (0x10)

"& #13;" <=> \r (0x13)

So in your text data from your user the carriage return is not present.
Could you show us how your text is inserted in your DB ?

Comment: I use $_POST['care_advice_message'] = filter_var($_POST['care_advice_message'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
and then a simple sql update

Comment: You should use a prepared statement, this way you don't have to manage this issue but try to use [mysqli_espace_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead of filter_var.

Answer (score 0):

replace all spaces

```
str_replace(" ","",$yourstring)
```

and new line characters

```
str_replace("\n","",$yourstring);
```

and convert it to lower case by

```
strtolower($yourstring);
```

then try to compare it.